# Hermitian Octonion matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, octonions

The space of $n\times n$ octionion matrics $A$ such that $AA^*=A^*A=I_n$ is not a Lie group due to lack of associativity. But is it a smooth manifold? What is its dimension?

Comment: Tangent space at the identity has antihermitian matrices, so dimension is $8\binom{n}{2}+7n$. I assume some annoying calculation shows it's a smooth variety.

Comment: Of course for $n = 1$ the set can be identified with $S^7$.